# If the element(s) in the first list equal element(s) of the second list, replace with element(s) of the third list

Tags: r, string, list

I have three lists

##### Example Data

```
data <- list("A-B", "C-D", "E-F", "G-H", "I-J")
data_to_replace  <- list("A-B", "C-D")
replacement <- list("B-A", "D-C")
## Note: The length(data_to_replace)  and length(replacement ) are always equal. Which may range from 1 to 200
```

This is just a minimal example. I have several of these three, and the number varies on each list

##### Expected outcome

```
data_new <- list("B-A", "D-C", "E-F", "G-H", "I-J")
```

##### What I have tried

```
## function that reverses a string by words
reverse_words <- function(string) {
  ## split string by blank spaces
  string_split <- strsplit(as.character(string), split="-")
  ## How many split terms?
  string_length <- length(string_split[[1]])
  ## decide what to do
  if (string_length == 1) {
    ## one word (do nothing)
    reversed_string <- string_split[[1]]
  } else {
    ## more than one word (collapse them)
    reversed_split <- string_split[[1]][string_length:1]
    reversed_string <- paste(reversed_split, collapse="-")
  }
  ## output
  return(reversed_string)
} 

## Replacemnt
replacement <- lapply(data_to_replace, reverse_words)
data_new <- rapply(data, function(x) {
  replace(x, x == data_to_replace, replacement) ## This last line did not work
})
```

Comment: Why are you using `list`s instead of `character` vectors here? If you use vectors instead, `data =c("A-B", "C-D", "E-F", "G-H", "I-J")`, 
`data_to_replace = c("A-B", "C-D")`, 
and `replacement = c("B-A", "D-C")`, then it is much simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert your inputs to vectors and then you can do this:

```
## direct replacement
data[data %in% data_to_replace] = replacement[match(data, data_to_replace)]

## or with `ifelse` if you want to save it as a new name 
## and keep `data` unmodified
ifelse(data %in% data_to_replace, replacement[match(data, data_to_replace)], data)
```

Answer (score 3):

This already existys in `stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed`.

```
> data[] <- stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(data, data_to_replace, 
+                                           replacement, 
+                                           vectorize_all=FALSE)
> data
[[1]]
[1] "B-A"

[[2]]
[1] "D-C"

[[3]]
[1] "E-F"

[[4]]
[1] "G-H"

[[5]]
[1] "I-J"
```

Note, there's also a `stringi::stri_replace_all_regex`.

Maybe the `reverse_words()` function can be simplified.

```
> reverse_words2 <- \(x) paste(rev(el(strsplit(x, '-'))), collapse='-')
> (replacement <- lapply(data_to_replace, reverse_words2))
[[1]]
[1] "B-A"

[[2]]
[1] "D-C"
```

Comment: Yeah, but you're using regex to check for equality matches.... works fine on this toy data but if anything is more complicated then you have to worry about inadvertent partial matches and regex special characters. You can solve those complications by sanitizing and complicating the regex, but overall I think it's much better practice to avoid using regex when whole-string-equality is all that's needed.

Comment: @GregorThomas Agreed, use `*fixed`, `*regex` is overkill.

Comment: Yeah, but if you use `*fixed`, you can't do anything about partial matches. Use `==`, or equivalently, `match`.

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you can simply use `replace` + `match`

```
> replace(data, match(data_to_replace, data), replacement)
[[1]]
[1] "B-A"

[[2]]
[1] "D-C"

[[3]]
[1] "E-F"

[[4]]
[1] "G-H"

[[5]]
[1] "I-J"
```